# MotionEvent Issues

Tags: android

I was wondering how to get accurate, get(x) and get(y) values for a MotionEvent? What is happening is that when I touch a specific area on the screen, I tell an action to happen.
The problem is that once I touch the screen and take my finger off, it still thinks my finger is at the same location (since that was the last location I touched). So when I have more than one Down event (for multitouch) it throws everything off. Is there a way to reset the X and Y values so when I let off the screen, they go back to 0 or null (or whatever)?

Here is a video I just uploaded to explain it better, cause it is kind of confusing

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHGj2z5SwQs

And here is the exact code I'm using

```
    int x = (int) e.getX();
    int y = (int) e.getY();
    int x2 = (int) e.getX(1);
    int y2 = (int) e.getY(1);


    boolean a1 = y > 0 && y < 200....etc        

    boolean a5 = etc... 

    switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x =  0;
        y = 0;          
        x2 = 0;
        y2 = 0;
                    ////I'm setting the x and y values to 0 as suggested

        text.setText("x:" + String.valueOf(x) + "y:" + String.valueOf(y));
                    //// This is so I can see the values on the screen
        if (a1 && a5){
            viewA1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            viewA5.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        if (a1) {

            viewA1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }



        else if (a5) {
            viewA5.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        }           



        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN:
        // /A Strummer
        x =  0;
        y = 0;

        x2 = 0;
        y2 = 0;

        text1.setText("x:" + String.valueOf(x2) + "y:" + String.valueOf(y2));
        if (a1 && a5){

            viewA1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            viewA5.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        }
        if (a1) {

            viewA1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }



        else if (a5) {

            viewA1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        }       
     /////I have pretty much the same method for ACTION_UP & ACTION_POINTER_UP; I set x & y to 0.
```

Please let me know if you can think of anything. I tried the methods you guys explained and it would seem like it would help, but it hasn't.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a tip but a working solution and some tips for multitouch starters. I never did that before so after seeing your question I was eager to now how multitouch works. And actually it's pretty tricky to get it done right. This is a great example for startes (view with four corners which are colored when one of the pointers is touching it - works with one up to five pointers / fingers). So I will explain it based on the working solution posted further below.

Basically it works like this: [getPointerCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount%28%29) is giving you the amount of currently touching pointers. [getX(i)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX%28int%29) and [getY(i)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getY%28int%29) are giving you the corresponding coordinates. But this part is tricky: pointer 0, 1, 2 are touching, you lift 1 (second finger), and now you have 0, 1. This is the point where [getPointerId(1)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId%28int%29) will return 2 because this is still your pointer 2 which is touching but it's now on position 1 instead 2. You have a single chance to react on that change, that's when [ACTION_POINTER_UP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_POINTER_UP) is fired. On this action and on [ACTION_POINTER_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) [getActionIndex()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getActionIndex%28%29) will return the action pointer *position* of the pointer which was added or removed from pointer event list. Otherwise it's returning always 0 and that's something nobody tells you.

The conclusion is that *you can't actually track which pointer is moving* (that's why [getActionIndex()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getActionIndex%28%29) is return 0 on move). That seems ridiculously logical because it would be stupid to fire 5 separate events for each finger. But while starting with multitouch that's a really non trivial fact ;-)

Here's the example. `coordsX` and `coordsY` will track the pointer coordinates and if position 2 contains valid coordinates, it means that this is your third finger which is still touching the screen whether you lifted the other fingers or not. This might not be relevant in this case but it's a fact which could still be useful in other multitouch implementations.

```
public class MultitouchView extends LinearLayout {

    // we have a maximum of 5 pointer
    // we will set Integer.MIN_VALUE if the pointer is not present
    private int [] coordsX = new int [5];
    private int [] coordsY = new int [5];

    // add 4 views with a certain gravity so they are placed in corners
    public MultitouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // initialize as not present
        Arrays.fill(coordsX, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        Arrays.fill(coordsY, Integer.MIN_VALUE);


        /* the layout is inflated from a XML file and is basically this one:
         * all subviews are matching / filling parent and have a weight of 1
         * <LinearLayout vertical>
         *   <LinearLayout horizontal>
         *     <View /><View />
         *   </LinearLayout>
         *   <LinearLayout horizontal>
         *     <View /><View />
         *   </LinearLayout>
         * </LinearLayout>
         */
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            // every touch is going to be canceled, clear everything
            Arrays.fill(coordsX, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            Arrays.fill(coordsY, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        } else {
            // track all touches
            for (int i = 0; i < e.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                int id = e.getPointerId(i);

                if (e.getActionIndex() == i
                        && (e.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP
                        || e.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
                    // pointer with this id is about to leave, clear it
                    coordsX[id] = coordsY[id] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                } else {
                    // update all other pointer positions
                    coordsX[id] = (int) e.getX(i);
                    coordsY[id] = (int) e.getY(i);
                }
            }
        }

        int hw = getWidth() / 2;
        int hh = getHeight() / 2;

        // first no corner is touched
        boolean topLeft = false, topRight = false, bottomRight = false, bottomLeft = false;

        // check if any of the given pointer is touching a certain corner
        for (int i = 0; i < coordsX.length; i++) {
            // pointer is not active (anymore)
            if (coordsX[i] == Integer.MIN_VALUE || coordsY[i] == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                continue;
            }

            topLeft = topLeft || coordsX[i] < hw && coordsY[i] < hh;
            topRight = topRight || coordsX[i] > hw && coordsY[i] < hh;
            bottomRight = bottomRight || coordsX[i] > hw && coordsY[i] > hh;
            bottomLeft = bottomLeft || coordsX[i] < hw && coordsY[i] > hh;
        }

        // set the result we have now to the views represnting the corners
        ((ViewGroup) getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(topLeft ? 0xffffff00 : 0x0);
        ((ViewGroup) getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(topRight ? 0xffff0000 : 0x0);
        ((ViewGroup) getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(bottomLeft ? 0xff00ff00 : 0x0);
        ((ViewGroup) getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(bottomRight ? 0xff0000ff : 0x0);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Knickedi I wish I could say it did, but, for me anyway, it only complicated things. I don't see why what I am trying to achieve would be as code heavy as what you suggested, although I am most likely wrong, because the methods I am trying to use apparently isn't working.

Comment: One question though, do I have to extend a View and use a OnTouchEvent, or can I extend an Activity and use on OnTouch? I have been using the latter, because the former seems more complicated to me. I don't know though, I have been learning Java/Android for only about 6 weeks and it seemed to be going smooth until I hit this, and now it's like I hit a brick wall. I think I need to go back to the basics... D-:

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you would know the answer to this or not, but why isn't it as simple as using ACTION_DOWN for the first finger, and ACTION_POINTER_DOWN for the second, and so on?

Comment: Lastly, thanks a lot for the effort you put in to trying to help, I appreciate it

Comment: 1. I wouldn't say that my solution is code heavy, maybe theres a shorter version for two fingers only but I don't think it will look cleaner than mine. 2. An activity can't listen to touch events. You can [attach a listener to a view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) or create a custom view and override the touch event method. 3. You can listen to those events that way but you have to know that ACTION_POINTER_UP will be fired for the first finger which is lifted even if finger triggered ACTION_DOWN before

Comment: Alright. What I'm trying to do now is I copied and pasted your code, and I am going to try to see exactly how it works and then alter it to try and get what I want to achieve. I noticed that on this line : ""for (int i = 0; i < coords.length; i++)""   "coords" is invalid, and it wants me to create a class. What should I do for this? That is the only error I'm getting

Comment: Sorry, typo. That happens if you correct code without an IDE ;-) I corrected it.

Comment: I'll give it another go and try to dissect it and hopefully get this thing working! Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I have a stupid question.... How do I inflate an XML? I am completely unfamiliar with that term.... Is there a tutorial you could direct me to? :-p

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, how did you learn to develop for android? Did you learn Java first and then build your knowledge off of it, or is it something you kind of learned as you went? I'm deciding wether or not to keep watching android developing tutorials on YouTube, or to follow the official Java tutorials on this page http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: It hurts to post again (this is comment section, not a chat). [Here a inflate article](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=303). You can see what I did [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/viktorreiser) in the background section at the bottom. When starting with android I think basic Java knowledge is a big advantage. If you wish we can meet in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ‘motionEvent.getPoinerCount()‘ to check the number of touch points.

Comment: @ Peter Knego  I just did that, and the PointerCount is accurate. Any other ideas?