# Android MotionEvent getY(int): Which call is the correct way?

Tags: android, events

Just a quick question to confirm the documentation:

The [getY(int) function from MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getY%28int%29) in the Android confuses me with its documentation:

> Returns the Y coordinate of this event for the given pointer index (use getPointerId(int) to find the pointer identifier for this index). Whole numbers are pixels; the value may have a fraction for input devices that are sub-pixel precise.

With that I thought that the code should be written like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); ++i) {
    // Some code...
    int currentPointer = event.getPointerId(i);
    float currentY = event.getY(currentPointer);
    Log.i("test", "Pointer " + currentPointer + " has Y-coord of " + currentY);
    // Some more code ...
}
```

However, in testing on my Samsung Galaxy Tab it appears that I should not pass currentPointer into getY but rather just the 'i' like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); ++i) {
    // Some code...
    int currentPointer = event.getPointerId(i);
    float currentY = event.getY(i);
    Log.i("test", "Pointer " + currentPointer + " has Y-coord of " + currentY);
    // Some more code ...
}
```

Is that the correct way of using the getPointerId and getY functions? You give them the both the same 'i' variable and never their actual pointer id's?

I am asking because I want to make sure that this is not different on just my device and this is indeed the way that it is intended to work. Thanks.

Comment: I struggled with that one too. Maybe my answer on [MotionEvent issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545591/motionevent-issues/7577139#7577139) will help you to understand it better...

Comment: @Knickedi Thankyou that confirms what I had just discovered for myself. That is exactly the way that it all seems to work but some of that is non obvious when you start attempting multitouch.

Comment: Glad that this answer wasn't for nothing and helped you. There are some really confusing things about multitouch and as you stated the documentation is not helpful either and is confusing you more than helping you to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct, you should specify only "i".

All the getPointer*(int) methods take the same index as parameter.