# how to implement multitouch gesture in android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, multi-touch

I have developed an app in which a cube is shown by `OpenGL ES` and when the user touches the screen & swipes it the cube gets translated from one position to another(sort of panning implementation)--implemented with `glTranslatef()`

I have used  `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` for this swipe movement. Now my problem is dat I want to implement this using the multi-touch, so the user has to use atleast two fingers for this translation.

Already tried using `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` & `ScaleGestureDetector` but stil its not clear.

Can anyone help me regardin this. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You can find a detailed description how multitouch works [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7577139/920511). Maybe this will help you to understand multitouch...

Comment: thnks a lot Knickedi !! the getPointerCount() function did wat i was lukin for :)

Comment: Then please add your answer.

Comment: getPointerCount() worked as I mentioned above